# Sub-menu items not placed correctly

Tags: css

I want the menu subitems to appear just under the menu items. As it is now, they are a bit to right.

**CSS**

```
ul#menu {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
    background-color:#D60024;
}

ul#menu > li {
    float:left;
    display:inline;
    position:relative;
    padding:3px;
    border:1px #8a0505 solid;
    background-color:#D60024;
    color:white;
}

ul#menu > li:hover {
    background:#8a0505;
    color:white;
}

ul#menu > li:hover ul {
    opacity:1;
    left:0;
    height:auto;
}

ul#menu li ul {
    position:absolute;
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    height:0;
    padding: 5px;
    margin:0;
    opacity:0;
}

ul#menu ul li {
    background-color:#D60024;
    border:1px #8a0505 solid;
}

ul#menu ul li:hover {
    background:#8a0505;
    border:1px #8a0505 solid;
    color:white;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sTQLh/1/)

Comment: you have all side apply padding so remove just left padding using padding: 5px 5px 5px 0; this one perfact your css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modify in your css this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sTQLh/2/)**

```
ul#menu > li:hover ul {
    opacity:1;
    left:-6px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

is not the best solution, but it does what you want

edit this

```
ul#menu ul li {
   background-color:#D60024;
   border:1px #8a0505 solid;
}
```

in this

```
ul#menu ul li {
   background-color:#D60024;
   border:1px #8a0505 solid;
   margin-left:-6px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Working Solution: http://jsfiddle.net/avi_sagi/sTQLh/11/

In css rules for

```
ul#menu li ul { 
    padding: 6px;
}
```

I am assuming u gave it to align the dropdown list items to the bottom of the main menu items.
It is creating the space to the left

The right CSS rule should have been.

```
ul#menu li ul {
  padding: 0px;
  margin:4px 0 0 -1px;
}
```

margin-left:-1px is provided to pull the dropdown left because the 1px border of the main menu is pushing the dropdown it being the main menu list item's child element. its your wish to use it or not.

Its a bad practice to use padding instead of margin. both create spaces but their definition is different and their misuse might create problems.
secondly, these kind of problems arise commonly use Inspect Element or Firebug to see why these spaces are created.

Hope this Helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/39james/MKtRe/)

CSS changes

```
ul#menu li ul {
    padding: 0;
    top:100%;
    margin-left:-2px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ul#menu li ul {
    position:absolute;
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    height:0;
    padding: 5px;  // to  change padding: 5px 5px 5px 0;
    margin:0;
    opacity:0;
}
```

See demo [your Demo edited](http://jsfiddle.net/sTQLh/12/)